# Upload csv files from ftp into SF via Apex (without insertFile Tag)

Tags: apex, csv, upload, fileupload

I want to automatically upload csv files into Salesforce on a regular basis, doing a scheduled job. I want to have this job centralized so that everybody has access to the code and the process. I want to do proper error handling so that the users get notified in case an upload fails. Due to company policies, we cannot access the database directly, only the csv on a ftp server. Can the upload be done without middleware?

Comment: Is it possible for you to add @RestResource for this case? (add REST interface)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please read about the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), which may be relevant here. Also, the way your question is phrased, it appears that there is no solution, as you've eliminated all the usual methods for getting a file in to Apex. Describing exactly why you need this file would be helpful.

Comment: I think @RestResource does not help here, the connector is very restricted. Or can you specify what you mean by your suggestion?

Comment: Apex cannot speak FTP directly. I've connected some existing questions that review this challenge.